# Finder reverse engineering

Tags: xcode, macos, monitoring, finder

I am try to find out what methods the Finder calls in each action. For example, when drawing icons, when showing file list etc. I was able find out some but fail with others. I was looking for program like strace. All I can find was Instruments but I was not able to attach to the Finder with it. Do you know other program that can record all the Finder calls ?

Comment: Attaching Instruments from XCode 4 to Finder on Lion works fine for me.

Comment: In Lion it does, In Snow Leopard it does not. I need a solution to Snow Leopard also.